# ObjC, Swift to WinObjC

Tags: winobjc

I have an iOS app which includes both objective c and swift. Does the `winobjc` tool support converting the iOS apps which includes both objective c and swift code?

Answer (score 1):

I work on the Windows Bridge for iOS at Microsoft. We're getting more and more questions about Swift support and it's clearly a top priority for the community. Now that Apple has open sourced large parts of Swift, we're considering our options and the technical implications of implementing it.

We regularly update our [roadmap](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinObjC/wiki/Roadmap) on our project wiki with our plans for the next month or two, so there is the best place to check for near-term plans. If you try out the bridge and have any questions, please don't hesitate to [get in touch](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinObjC/issues/new) by filing an issue on Github. Thanks for checking out the bridge!

Answer (score 0):

No, WinObjC only supports Objective-C but no Swift at this point.

It also doesn’t seem to be on [their roadmap](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinObjC/wiki/Roadmap) at this point.